# Getting an error after initial firebase setup in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

Getting this error, how do I totally get the firebase out of my Xcode project? I don't really need to know the right way of getting it back in, but how do I fully get it out? Thanks! Here's a screenshot of my error.

[image]

Comment: How did you add firebase to your project?  did you use `cocoapods` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocoapods, just delete this pod 'Firebase/Core' line from your podfile and again update pod from terminal.